# Add the date in the bottom

Tags: header-footer

With the following codes

```
     \documentclass[12pt, reqno]{amsart}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amscd, amsfonts, amssymb, graphicx, color}
    \usepackage[bookmarksnumbered, colorlinks, plainpages]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red, anchorcolor=green, citecolor=cyan, urlcolor=red, filecolor=magenta, pdftoolbar=true}

    \textheight 22.5truecm \textwidth 15truecm
    \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.25in}\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.25in}
     \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
    \setlength{\topmargin}{-.5cm}


     \begin{document}
    \title[]{}
   \subjclass[2010]{Primary 47B99; Secondary 47A05.}

    \keywords{m-isometry, strict m-isometry n-quasi-m-isometry.}
    \maketitle
    \end{document}
```

I get

[image]

However I hope to get

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `\date{\emph{December 3-2018}}` in your code.

```
    \documentclass[12pt, reqno]{amsart}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amscd, amsfonts, amssymb, graphicx, color}
    \usepackage[bookmarksnumbered, colorlinks, plainpages]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red, anchorcolor=green, citecolor=cyan, urlcolor=red, filecolor=magenta, pdftoolbar=true}

    \textheight 22.5truecm \textwidth 15truecm
    \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.25in}\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.25in}
     \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
    \setlength{\topmargin}{-.5cm}


     \begin{document}
    \title[]{}
    \today{\emph{December 3-2018}}
   \subjclass[2010]{Primary 47B99; Secondary 47A05.}

    \keywords{m-isometry, strict m-isometry n-quasi-m-isometry.}
    \maketitle

    \end{document}
```

[image]